# vim-textobj-entire does not work if "e" not typed immediately after "a" or "i"

Tags: normal-mode

I'm using Neovim v0.7.2 with Kana Natsuno's `vim-textobj-entire` plugin, but I observed that when using `ae` or `ie` after some operator (say doing something like `g~ae` to toggle the case of an entire buffer) the command will not work if there is a long pause between typing the `a` or `i` and the `e`. I checked that this isn't the typical behaviour by confirming that I can wait as long as I like between typing, say, the `i` and the `w` in `g~iw`. I'm not sure why this issue exists and why it only affects user-defined text objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to the `'timeout'` setting. If you don’t want mappings to time out:

```
:set notimeout
```

Alternatively, you can alter the length of the timeout, which defaults to 1,000ms. e.g.:

```
:set timeoutlen=5000
```

One reason you might *not* want to unset `'timeout'` is if you have mappings that start with another mapping or standard command. e.g. if you mapped `;;` to do something and turned off time outs, then you could never use the `;` command to repeat the most recent 'f' motion.

With a sufficiently short `'timeoutlen'`, you can still use `;` by waiting for the time out to occur.